# Plot multiple time series from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, line

*I want to plot sales in Y axe and time in X axe. One line per each car model. I managed to plot one line for the total sales. Any suggestions to get lines for each car model?*

```
cars = {"Date" : ["2020-01-29", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-24", "2020-05-21", "2020-12-31", "2020-12-01", "2020-12-01"],
    "Brand": ["Honda Civic","Toyota Corolla","Honda Civic", "Ford Focus","Audi A4", "Ford Focus", "Ford Focus"],
    "Price": [22000,25000,22000,27000,35000,27000,27000]
    }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ["Date", "Brand", "Price"])
df2["Date"] =  pd.to_datetime(df2["Date"])
df2=df2.sort_values(by="Date")
df2.index = df2["Date"]
gb2=df2.groupby([df2.index.year.values,df2.index.month.values,df2.index.day.values]).sum()
gb2.plot.line()
plt.show()
```

Comment: There are many tutorials for plotting in python.  Matplotlib is a popular module, and pandas integrates with matplotlib.  For plotting series, see, for example, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html -- However, the data that you are attempting to plot does not appear to be appropriate to the kind of plot you are trying to create.  In particular, there does not appear to be a price history for each car model.  Please check that your data is appropriate for the plot you want to make.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can plot a line per car model via the following. Note that the `marker` is used because lines in isolation would not show any plot data for the Toyota Corolla or Audi A4, which are represented by only a single data point each.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for (i, b) in df2.groupby('Brand'):
    b.plot(x='Date', y='Price', marker='o', ax=ax, label=i)
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did it using Seaborn and got the same results.